# Why is my line not appearing on the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problems with the Google Maps javascript API. Basically, I would like to draw a polyline and not have the code within the initialize function, so what I currently have is:

```
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37, 103.814),
                zoom: 11
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
        }

        function test() {
            var itwCoordinates = [
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.1955, 103.566667),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.19875, 103.572333),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.188167, 103.660694),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.179444, 103.670722),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.130361, 103.740694),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.171444, 103.805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.195972, 103.859833),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.20725, 103.88075),
                new google.maps.LatLng(1.2695, 104.033333)
            ];
            var itwLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: itwCoordinates,
                map: map,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#777777',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 1
            });
            itwLine.setMap(map);
            itwLine.setVisible(true);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have a button on the document itself that will call the function test() upon clicking it, however it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

In general, what I would like to ask is how can I draw shapes on the map without including the data in the initialize function?

Comment: Did stored map to Global called??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing store **map**, declare **map** is Global variables,

```
   var map;
    function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37, 103.814),
               zoom: 11
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see, can't believe I didn't catch such a basic mistake

Comment: if my answer has help full please, vote up or check it accept.